# How to assemble for MIPS cpu in the gnu assembler

Tags: assembly, mips, gnu, gnu-assembler

I learning MIPS assembly and I want to assemble a MIPS assembly using `as` or `gas` command

Looking at the [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/as)
I tried to assemble using

```
as -mips32 myfile.asm
```

But it said it is an unrecognized option

I also tried to use

```
as -march=r3000 myfile.asm
```

but that also didn't work it said

> Assembler messages: Fatal error: invalid -march= option: `r3000'

So, how do you assemble MIPS assembly using the gnu assembler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a version of GNU Binutils built to target MIPS?  It's not like clang where you can use `clang -target mips -march=mips1 -c foo.s` && `llvm-objdump -d foo.o`  (MIPS1 includes R2000 and R3000).

For example, to run GAS for ARM on my x86-64 desktop, I can run `arm-none-eabi-as` since I installed the `arm-none-eabi-binutils` package on my Arch Linux system.  You'd need something similar, or configure and build Binutils from source yourself, to get a `mips-something-something-as` executable you could run.

Just plain `as` (`/usr/bin/as`) will be a native assembler for your system, so x86-64 if you're on x86-64, with no support for other ISAs.  (Except for i386 with `as --32` because Binutils considers amd64 and i386 as different versions of the same ISA).